# Android capturar rotação do aparelho sem rotacionar o aplicativo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, rotação, orientation

Tenho uma aplicação com Android Webview, minha activity está configurada para `portrait`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize"></activity>
```

Mas gostaria de pegar o evento de quando o usuário rotaciona o aparelho e a tela do app continue em `portrait`, mas necessito de pegar esse evento para fazer uma animação de apenas um video de dentro da webview faça uma animação e rotacione também. Alguém tem uma solução para esse caso?

Comment: Observe a seguinte [discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12350870/10304819)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução encontrada:

```
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener()
    {
        int orientation = -1;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
        {
            if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5)
            {
                if (orientation != 1)
                {
                    Log.d("SensorLog", "Landscape");
                }
                orientation = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (orientation != 0)
                {
                    Log.d("SensorLog", "Portrait");
                }
                orientation = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```